# Resolving promises in rendering htmlwidgets

Tags: r, promise, shiny, future, htmlwidgets

I was wondering if anyone could help with how the htmlwidgets and associated render functions work with promises (i.e `promises` and `future` packages) in `shiny`.

I have been reading up and learning on how to integrate these things based on Joe Chengs articles and rstudioconf talk. E.g

https://medium.com/@joe.cheng/async-programming-in-r-and-shiny-ebe8c5010790
https://medium.com/@joe.cheng/an-informal-intro-to-async-shiny-cbf01c85c4c5

https://www.rstudio.com/resources/videos/scaling-shiny-apps-with-async-programming/ (nice talk by the way)

An issue was raised on the github repo for the `promises` package concerning DT but it was stated that most htmlwidget packages will not need modification.

https://github.com/rstudio/promises/issues/10

I have tried numerous things to get htmlwidgets to render from promises but can't get this working with shiny. For example with `dygraphs` and `leaflet` the following works outside of shiny (A standard `plot()` is also included as a reference)

```
library(promises)
library(future)
plan(multiprocess)
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(dygraphs)

expensive_operation = function(){
  Sys.sleep(2)
  data.frame(x=runif(10))
}

future({ expensive_operation() }) %...>% plot
future({ expensive_operation() }) %...>%
{leaflet(.) %>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers(~x,~x) %>% print}
future({ expensive_operation()}) %...>% {
  dygraph(.) %>% print
}
```

All fine so far.

I have installed the dev version of `shiny` from github. But in the following:

```
ui = fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("l"),
  plotOutput("p"),
  dygraphOutput("d")
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  output$p = renderPlot({
    future({ expensive_operation() }) %...>% plot
  })
  output$l <- renderLeaflet({
    ## neither 
    # future({ expensive_operation() }) %...>%
    # {leaflet(.) %>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers(~x,~x) %>% print} # prints in rstudio viewer
    # nor
    future({ expensive_operation() }) %...>%
    {leaflet(.) %>% addTiles()%>% addMarkers(~x,~x)} # does nothing
    # work
  })

  #similar story to leaflet
  output$d = renderDygraph({
    # future({ expensive_operation()}) %...>% {
    #   dygraph(.) %>% print
    # }
    future({ expensive_operation()}) %...>% {
      dygraph(.)
    }

  })
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui,server))
```

only the standard plot actually renders. Neither the commented out version  with a call to `print` or the other will do anything inside the shiny app. Including `print` does allow this to be printed to the rstudio viewer but this isn't fit for purpose.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to where I am misunderstanding or going wrong?

Comment: Please confirm if this is still an issue. I have a fresh install from github for the supporting packages outlined [here](https://rstudio.github.io/promises/index.html) and could render all three plots in the shiny app.

Comment: The 3 plots work fine for me too.